# Get serializer fields in RelatedField serializer django rest

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

```
class ScreenCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    screen = ScreenListingField(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ScreenCategory
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'screen', 'active', 'position']

class ScreenListingField(serializers.RelatedField):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        res = {}
        # Need get ScreenCategory id here
        res['id'] = value.id
        res['title'] = value.title
        res['layout'] = value.layout
        res['project'] = value.project.id
        res['last_change'] = value.last_change
        res['width'] = value.width
        res['height'] = value.height
        res['background_color'] = value.background_color
        if value.constant_color is None:
            res['constant_color'] = None
        else:
            res['constant_color'] = value.constant_color.id
        res['styles'] = value.styles
        res['base'] = value.base
        return res
```

I have the following serializer, inside the ScreenListingField I would like to get the id of the ScreenCategory. How can I get it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access forgin key value in react from django api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67523331/how-to-access-forgin-key-value-in-react-from-django-api)

Comment: Maybe get it by overriding `to_representation` of `ScreenCategorySerializer` and inject it on the representation of `screen` field? But just curious why you need it? You already have the id from the parent?

Comment: @bdbd Based on the id, additional data will need to be retrieved and displayed in screen

Comment: Hmm I see. Maybe use a serializer method field in `ScreenCategorySerializer`?

Comment: @bdbd Thanks for the advice. I used it and implemented what I needed.